# Excel VBA output multiple columns to text file

Tags: excel, vba, output

I'm trying to create an Excel VBA script which will take 2 columns as input and output the values of into a text file.

e.g

A1: 123
B1: avenue

A2:231
B2: another lane

I'm after an output in a txt file that looks something like this:

> House number: 123 Street name: avenue
>
> ----.
>
> House number: 231 Street name: another lane
>
> ----.

Basically what i'm looking for is:
"House number: "+A1+ " Street name: "+B2
"------"

I've got this to work with just 1 column however I'm stuck with adding a second.

```
Sub CreatetestScript()

    If Dir("C:\test.txt") <> "" Then
     Kill ("C:\test.txt")
    End If

    Sheets("test").Select
    Dim acolumn As String

    r = 2
    Do While Cells(r, 1) <> ""
        acolumn = Cells(r, 1).Value
        run (Cells(r, 1))
        r = r + 1
    Loop

End Sub
Sub run(ByVal acolumn As String)

Dim fileName As String
fileName = "C:\test.txt"

Open fileName For Append As #1

    Print #1, ""
    Print #1, "House Number = " + acolumn
    Print #1, "--------------"

Close #1

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go many directions with this, one way would be creating a bcolumn variable and setting it to the next cell's index in your row:

```
Sub CreatetestScript()

    If Dir("C:\test.txt") <> "" Then
     Kill ("C:\test.txt")
    End If

    Sheets("test").Select
    Dim acolumn As String
    Dim bColumn As String
    r = 2
    Do While Cells(r, 1) <> ""
        acolumn = Cells(r, 1).Value
        bColumn = Cells(r,2).value
        run (Cells(r, 1), Cells(r,2))
        r = r + 1
    Loop

End Sub
Sub run(ByVal acolumn As String, ByVal Bcolumn As String)

Dim fileName As String
fileName = "C:\test.txt"

Open fileName For Append As #1

    Print #1, ""
    Print #1, "House Number = " + acolumn
    Print #1, "--------------"
    Print #1, ","
    Print #1, "Street = " + Bcolumn
    Print #1, "--------------"
Close #1

End Sub
```

Your output may need formatted differently, but this should get you on track.  For a little reusability, You could setup the function to take an array of these strings too.

Comment: HI,
Thanks for the answer, I get a compile error Argument not optional error message

Comment: I wasn't providing the new value to the run function.  Please see my change and let me know if we're on the right track here :)

Comment: you're too fast. Just tried that.

Thanks for your help